# Free Rails UI components for Simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend, simple-form

I would like to know if there is a site to download or copy awesome and  free Rails UI components for stuff like Simple form, cards, buttons etc. That would save some fronted development work.

Comment: The UI stuff is independent of rails. You embed rails into UI. So if you're looking for some UI templates, search for bootstrap, template etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hakeem,

If you want to save time you can use Bootstrap, Fontawesome, Foundation, Semantic UI, etc.. frameworks to help with forms, buttons, navs etc.  If you do use a different view framework/library like React these will work as well so it's your best bet to save some time if it's heavy usage on your web-app.